# UIPickerViewの初期値をuserdefaultに保存し、適用したい

Tags: swift

Swiftで以下のコードを試してみました。([参考にしたコード](https://github.com/zhiyao92/PickerView-on-AlertController/blob/master/Picker%20View%20Alert%20Controller/ViewController.swift))

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    //ユーザー設定
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var choices = ["Toyota","Honda","Chevy","Audi","BMW"]
    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    var typeValue = String()

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.userDefaults.register(defaults: ["pickerviewSelectRow": 0])
    }
    
    //MARK - PickerView
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return choices.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return choices[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row == 0 {
            typeValue = "Toyota"
        } else if row == 1 {
            typeValue = "Honda"
        } else if row == 2 {
            typeValue = "Chevy"
        } else if row == 3 {
            typeValue = "Audi"
        } else if row == 4 {
            typeValue = "BMW"
        }
        self.userDefaults.set(row, forKey: "pickerviewSelectRow")
        self.userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

    //MARK - UIAlertController
    
    @IBAction func showChoices(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Car Choices", message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
        //alert.isModalInPopover = true
        
        let pickerFrame = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 20, width: 250, height: 140))
        
        
        let pickerviewSelectRow = self.userDefaults.object(forKey: "pickerviewSelectRow") as! Int
        pickerFrame.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true) // 初期値 liveStreamPickerViewSelect
        
        pickerFrame.dataSource = self
        pickerFrame.delegate = self
        alert.view.addSubview(pickerFrame)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            
            print("You selected " + self.typeValue )
        
        }))
        self.present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil )
    }
}
```

userdefaultに値は保存されてはいるようなのですが、「Honda」などを選択してpickerviewを閉じたあとに、初期値を`selectRow`で指定しても毎回「Toyota」でpickerviewが起動してしまいます。

何が原因でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 何が原因でしょうか？

`selectRow(_:inComponent:animated:)`を呼び出すタイミングの問題でしょう。

私が試したところ、`dataSource`を設定した後なら動作するようです。

```
        pickerFrame.dataSource = self
        pickerFrame.selectRow(2/*pickerviewSelectRow*/, inComponent: 0, animated: true) // 初期値
        pickerFrame.delegate = self
        alert.view.addSubview(pickerFrame)
```

`dataSource`が設定されるまで、`UIPickerView`には選択肢がいくつあるかもわからないので、その中のどれかを選択しろと言われても困ると言うことだろうと思います。

---

ちなみに`UIAlertController`のview階層を直接いじると言ったことはApple側は想定していないので、別のバージョンのiOSで試してもうまくいくか(動作確認はXcode 12.0.1)は保証できません。

確実に動作させたい場合には、alertに似せた別画面(view controller)を作ってそれを表示してやると言ったことをしたほうがいいかもしれません。

---

ところで、あなたのコードでは現在`pickerView`なんてプロパティは全く使われていませんね。参考サイトのコードをコピペした状態のままなのでしょうが、コードが大きくなり複雑化してくるにつれ、そう言った使われてもいないプロパティ存在の弊害も大きくなっていくので、「もう使われていない」と分かった時点でさっさと削除してしまった方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 私の環境でも正常に動作しました。ありがとうございます。